# hibernate MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database "..."

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, jdbc

I just installed MySql Community Server, and I have a MySql Connection called mysqlserver. I created a schema called library, with some tables. Everything seems fine with the database, but when I try to generate bean classes with hibernate reverse engineering from Eclipse, I am getting this error:

```
 org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Getting database metadata
 Getting database metadata
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'mysqlserver'
 Unknown database 'mysqlserver'
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'mysqlserver'
 Unknown database 'mysqlserver'
```

The interesting thing is that my tables are fetching, so I can see them from Eclipse, but the error is still here while trying to generate classes.
My guess was that the problem is with my url, but how are tables fetched then:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

<property name="hibernate.connection.password">mypassword</property>

<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library</property>

<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>

<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

I do not get it how can mysqlserver be unknown database, when I specified that my database is library. I lost hours while trying to google it, and still nothing. Can anyone help me with this please?

Now, I am experiencing a new problem - I cannot start the server any more. I stopped it yesterday, and tried to start it now, it just won't start any more. The server log says:

```
Could not open error log file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'SAMS-PC.err'
2014-02-06 13:10:32 - Status check of service 'MySQL56' returned stopped
2014-02-06 13:10:32 - Starting server...
2014-02-06 13:10:34 - Status check of service 'MySQL56' returned stopped
2014-02-06 13:10:34 - Server start done.
2014-02-06 13:10:34 - Status check of service 'MySQL56' returned stopped
```

Comment: you forgot to define the db dialect https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html

Comment: Actually I didn't, I just didn't copy it:  property name="hibernate.dialect" ->org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect  Thanks for noticing

Comment: define db dialect. you can look this; http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the last issue, with starting the server from console. I don't know why MySql workbench didn't start it, but I will be satisfied with this solution for now. Later the server stopped working again, and so on... So, I concluded that I do not like MySql very much.

I solved the original problem, too. The problem was something unrelated to hibernate configuration - I forgot to create a .reveng.xml file. Embarrassing...

Anyway, thank you for willingness to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your jdbc string should be

```
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqlserver
hibernate.default_schema = library
```

you schema is library, you database name mysqlserver.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that yesterday, and with these parameters, my tables didn't fetch at all.